# How to set up proxy for webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use proxy with selenium web-driver like it described [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

But it does not work. What is wrong?

```
String PROXY = "host:port"; //real values
org.openqa.selenium.Proxy proxy = new org.openqa.selenium.Proxy();
proxy.setHttpProxy(PROXY)
         .setFtpProxy(PROXY)
         .setSslProxy(PROXY);
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);
driver.get("http://google.com/");
```

Firefox opens but shows nothing and finally I recive in the console:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

Comment: What is the firefox and selenium version you are using???

Comment: Is it working when  proxy  set in firefox browser ?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur latest firefox 48.0 and selenium-server version 2.53.1

Comment: You need to download [`geckdriver from here`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set it this downloaded path into system PATH variable and then modify your desire capability to support latest firefox as `cap.setCapability("marionette", true);`  and then run it

Comment: For more details follow this link.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

Comment: ff was downgraded and it finally works